# How to determine the most frequent month in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have a list of dates for the dates that it rained.

```
rained=["01-05-2012","05-01-2012","01-12-2012","06-14-2013"]
```

The order of the date is month,date,year. Looking at the list it can be seen that out of these dates given, it rained the most in January (01). How would I be able to create a code for this?

Comment: On which base, you can say "it rained the most in january(01)" ?

Comment: @NileshG The list presumably (only) contains the days in which it rained.

Comment: Because big-endian or little-endian dates are not enough choices

Answer (score 4):

Use `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> rained=["01-05-2012","05-01-2012","01-12-2012","06-14-2013"]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(x[:2] for x in rained).most_common()[0][0]
'01'
```

`most_common()` will return a list of tuples of the item and the count in the descending order:

```
>>> Counter(x[:2] for x in rained).most_common()
[('01', 2), ('06', 1), ('05', 1)]
```

Comment: I think you can just use `x[:2]` because if the months aren't all given as 0 padded, the result will be nonsense anyway

Answer (score 0):

use split() function to split every item in the list by symbol '-', and then analyze the months you can get the answer.

Comment: Say I start with `months_rained = [1,5,1,6]`, how can that be analyzed? (This question should be flushed out, perhaps with some demo code.)

Comment: make a dict, the key is the month, the value is times it rained, iterate the monthsRaines and then get the biggest value, the key is the answer

Comment: @user2864740, that's even easier. Just use `Counter(months_rained)`

Comment: @gnibbler yes maybe that's easier, but if he changes another language which doesn't have the function? I just talk about the general solution.

Answer (score 0):

In case there is a tie, you can do something like this

```
>>> rained=["01-05-2012", "05-01-2012", "01-12-2012", "06-14-2013"]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter(x[:2] for x in rained).most_common()
>>> [i for i, j in counts if j==counts[0][1]]
['01']
```

Here is an example with a tie

```
>>> rained=["01-05-2012", "05-01-2012", "01-12-2012", "06-14-2013", "06-12-2013"]
>>> counts = Counter(x[:2] for x in rained).most_common()
>>> [i for i, j in counts if j==counts[0][1]]
['01', '06']
```